# why does java inference fail

Tags: java, javac, type-inference

I have the following seemingly similar methods, `do1` and `do2`:

```
class Demo<A>{
    public <C> Iterable<C> do1(List<? super C> _a) {
        return null;
    }


    public <C extends D, D> Iterable<C> do2(List<D> _a) {
        return null;
    }

    {
        List<? extends A> leA = null;

        do2(leA);
        do1(leA);
    }
}
```

When I compile above code (javac 1.8.0_92), calling `do2(leA)` works while `do1(leA)` fails.

```
required: List<? super C>
found: List<CAP#1>
reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) C
(argument mismatch; List<CAP#1> cannot be converted to List<? super C>)
where C,A are type-variables:
  C extends Object declared in method <C>do1(List<? super C>)
  A extends Object declared in class Cache
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
  CAP#1 extends A from capture of ? extends A
```

Now I'm wondering: is this due to incomplete implementation of type inference in javac, or am I creating an invalid type-tree with the invocation of `do1(leA)`?

Because to my knowledge:

- in `do1(leA)`: `Capture(? extends A)` becomes a superType of C
- in `do2(leA)`: `Capture(? extends A)` becomes a superType of C (indirectly via: `Capture(? extends A) == D` and  `D :> C`

meaning in both situations `C` should (without errors) resolve to `"? extends A"`

Comment: I can reproduce that with JDK 1.8.0_51. FYI, Eclipse Mars.2 compiles it fine...

Comment: Compiles OK for me too using `1.8.0_91-b14`. IIRC, update 40 was buggy - this could have been one of the bugs. Maybe just update your java version.

Comment: thanks for the up, I updated to 1.8.0_92, still get the same compile error: http://pastebin.com/tEUfX2JC

Comment: @WouterVegter I had similar proble on eclipse mars (white it was working on eclipse luna). Switching to Mars.2 fixed it... I don't have time to formulate an answer and check if we have the same bugs, but you can compare with this bug report : bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=415734

Answer (score -2):

You need `extends C` not `super C`:

```
public <C> Iterable<C> do1(List<? extends C> _a) {
```

A `super` of `C` is and ancestor, not a subclass.

Comment: I have explored that option as well and that will compile (that will make the type-tree in do1 different from do2). But I´m interested why methods with seemingly similar type-trees don't both compile succesfully..